# Can I store vectors with more precision in pgvector?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgvector

I am trying to store deepface.DeepFace.represent image embedding in front_vector column with full precision.
-0.7108331918716431 This is the actual precision but **pgvector** stores this as -0.7108332.

Here is the code:

> ```
> from sqlalchemy import (Column,String,Integer,CHAR,
>                         Date,Float, DECIMAL,LargeBinary,select)
> from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
> from pgvector.sqlalchemy import Vector
> Base= declarative_base()
> class Student(Base):
>     __tablename__="student_details"
>     name = Column("name",String,nullable=False)
>     dob = Column("dob",Date,nullable=False)
>     gender = Column("gender",CHAR(10),nullable=False)
>     front_vector = Column("front_vector",Vector(128))
> ```

pgvector official website suggests [this](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector?tab=readme-ov-file#can-i-store-vectors-with-more-precision),

> CREATE TABLE items (id bigserial PRIMARY KEY, embedding double
> precision[]);

which I am not able to implement in sqlalchemy. Please provide a solution so I can store the vector with its full precision.

Comment: What do you mean by "this which does not work"? Have you ran that SQL on your db? What is the type of the column you are storing the data in?

Comment: front_vector = Column("front_vector",Double[])
front_vector = Column("front_vector",double precision[])
front_vector = Column("front_vector",Numeric[])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?


front_vector = Column("front_vector",Numeric)
column "front_vector" is of type numeric but the expression is of type numeric[]
LINE 1: bytea, ARRAY[ -0....


I am trying to store the vector with full precision in the Front_vector column. This syntax does not work in sqlalchemy, even if these data types work for vectors so why do we need pgvector.